# Website sign in form from terminal

Tags: html, shell, login-script

I am currently make a bash script that requires me to login in a website, download the main page ( witch includes some HTML tables) and after export the tables to a file!

The difficult part for me is to deal wihth the website login.
I try with curl (curl --user user:pass domain) but nothing worked as I would expected.

Please let me know if you would have  any idea of how to make it work or how to do it with a different way.

Thank you in advance

Website Source Code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="Googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>
    Starbase
  </title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function showLoading() {
        document.getElementById('lyrLoading').style.display = 'inline';
      }
      //]]>
  </script>
</head>

<body link="#000080" vlink="#000080" alink="#000080">
  <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="center">
          <p align="center">
            <img border="0" src="images/imgLogoSmall.gif" />
          </p>
          <p align="center">
            <font face="Arial" color="#FF0000" size="2">You need to enter both an e-mail address and password.</font>
          </p>
          <table border="0" width="250">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <form onsubmit="javascript:window.setTimeout('showLoading();', 1);" method="post" action="/index.asp" name="loginform" id="loginform">
                  <input type="hidden" name="process" value="1" />
                  <p align="center">
                    <font face="Arial"><img border="0" src="images/imgUser.gif" /><br />
           <input name="username" size="25" style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14;" /></font>
                  </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <font face="Arial"><img border="0" src="images/imgPassword.gif" /><br />
           <input type="password" name="password" size="25" style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14;" /></font>
                  </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <font face="Arial"><input type="image" src="http://picpaste.com/extpics/btnLogIn-UM9GoIxr.gif" name="B1" /></font>
                  </p>
                </form>
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <a href="passwordMgmt.asp?action=1" rel="nofollow"><font face="Arial,helvetica" size="1">Forgot password</font></a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                      <p align="center">
                        <a href="passwordMgmt.asp?action=2" rel="nofollow"><font face="Arial,helvetica" size="1">Change password</font></a>
                      </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    document.loginform.username.focus();
     //]]>
  </script>
  <div style="display: none; z-index: 5; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 260px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -130px; margin-left: -250px;" id="lyrLoading">
    <div align="center">
      <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div align="center">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border: 2px solid #A6CDF9" width="200" height="130">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img border="0" src="images/imgLoading.gif" width="32" height="32" align="right" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <p align="left">
                      <font face="arial,helvetica" size="2">Logging in...</font>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to log in with basic auth credentials.

Your webpage is expecting form data in the form:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/
```

So in your case you should provide something similar to:

```
curl --data "username=aUserName&password=thePassword" http://example.com/index.asp
```

Resources:

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: it didnt work, I get back to the as a result an invalid password html page. have you seen the source code. ??

Comment: as well is not a standard form post ( I dont know a lot about forms or post request )

Comment: Try adding the hidden input field to your post request data it could be some sort of required parameter. In the html you posted it states "process=1".

`curl --data "username=aUsername&password=thePassword&process=1" http://example.com/index.asp`

If that doesn't work then you will need to provide more information about the actual website you are trying to request this data from.

Comment: Just to make things a little clearer. Any input element in a form with a name can potentially be a required parameter. In your code I see four potential parameters: The username field, the password field, the hidden process field, and the submit button 'B1'. All of these could be required by the server to process the request. You haven't provided server code, so I can't tell what is and isn't required. If you don't have access to the server code then I suggest you use your browser's developer tools (network tab on chrome) to see what the data portion of the post request looks like.

Comment: all I am trying to do is to login to the page. I guess i need to fill up the username and password. as an outcome I will need to get the source code of the page after the login. it doesnt sees to work! I try all the previous advices you guys gave me !    what othe information would you need to help me!?   thanks in advance!

Comment: Just so that you know: All basic auth credentials are sent in base64 and you linked them via pastebin. First off, that server is telling you that rotaModel... has been moved to index.asp so you can chop off all of that. Next: the correct commands are:
`curl --data "process=1&username=i.stilianakos%40icloud.com&password=Tony2012&B1.x=118&B1.y=8" http://starbase.maplin.net/ -v -c ~/cookies` and `curl http://starbase.maplin.net/  -v -b ~/cookies`. **Finally** Those credentials are invalid for that server, `<font...>The e-mail address and password combination you entered is invalid.</font>`

Comment: The -c and -b commands are for allowing setting and reusing cookies from curl. **You never need --user on the curl command line for this server**